# WordPress media uploader javascript don't working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Wordpress media uploader js doesn't work.

Really I very very tried.
Other code page right why don't work I can't understanding.
How can I work this code?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($){


    var mediaUploader;

    $( '#upload-button' ).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( mediaUploader ){
            mediaUploader.open();
            return;
        }

        mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose a Profile Picture',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Picture'
            },
            multiple: false
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You need to put that code in your question, not as a comment

Comment: If you need to add additional information to your question then you should [edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/204922) your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update

Try this:

```
(function ($) {

 var mediaUploader;

    $( '#upload-button' ).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ( mediaUploader ){
            mediaUploader.open();
            return;
        }

        mediaUploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
            title: 'Choose a Profile Picture',
            button: {
                text: 'Choose Picture'
            },
            multiple: false
        });
          mediaUploader.open();
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I have updated the code (have added one extra line) and have tested the code with my theme/plugin. So, if it is still not working for you, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks  for help me problem just id it's wrong. id="uplu(o)ad-button" one person help me.